# Understanding (t) dt in a definition of pdf

Tags: statistics

I am learning stats from a book called *All of Statistics* and from Khan Academy, which is not as mathematically deep. I have an intuitive understanding of a pdf and cdf from Khan Academy.

All of statistics defines a cdf as

$F_x(x) = P(X \leq x) $

A few pages later it says that the function $ f_X $ is called the **probability density function**. It says we "a function is called the probability density function (pdf). We have that:

$F_x(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_x (t) dt $

What is the meaning of (t)dt in that definition? Ignoring the (t) dt part it would seem that the definition says that the cdf of x is the area under the pdf from negative infinity up to x. That makes sense to me. So what is the meaning $(t)dt$ in the definition? *All of Statistics* is a really careful book, so I am sure it is there for a reason.

Comment: The $(t)$ part doesn't belong to $dt$, it belongs to $f_X$. It's supposed to be $f_X(t)$, integrated with respect to $t$ from $-\infty$ to $x$.

Comment: @Arthur so it is $f_X(t)dt$? if so, then why is there no t in the bounds of the integral? can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is. $f_X(t)$ roughly tells you the probability that $X$ will be "close to" $t$.

Comment: @Arthur And t refers to all of the ts that fall between $ - \infty $ and x?

Comment: Yes. $t$ is the ("dummy") variable you use to make sense of the integration.

Comment: $$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(t)\, dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(u)\, du=\ldots $$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to be thinking in terms of areas. The comments
about $(t)$ and $dt$ are mathematically correct, but perhaps
not useful at your mathematical level. (This is going to be a long
answer, stop when you have your answer or it starts to get too
mathematical.)

The total area under the density function of a random variable $X$ is $1.$ The probability that $X$ lies in a particular interval $(a, b]$,
is written as $P(a < X \le b)$. It is the area beneath the
density curve $f_X$ above the interval $(a,b].$ The notation
$\int_a^b f_X(t)\,dt$ is the way mathematicians write that area.

The probability that the random variable $X$ is smaller than the
number $x$ is written: 
 $$P(X \le x) = P(-\infty < X \le x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)\,dt.$$

[The 'variable of integration' $t$ is part of the *process* of
numerical evaluation of the probability, not a part of the answer.
The integral could just as well be written $\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(\xi)\, d\xi$ or  $\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(Q)\, dQ,$ or with any other symbol. Hence the term "dummy variable."]

Once you have the CDF, you can use it to find probabilities of
various intervals. For example,
$$P(0 < X \le 1/2) = F_X(1/2) - F_X(0) = \int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt.$$

Here is a specific example:  Suppose the density function of $X$
is $f_X(x) = 2x,$ for $x$ between 0 and 1, and $f_X(x) = 0$ for
other values of $x.$ You can draw a sketch of it: mainly it looks
like a right triangle with vertices at $(0,1), (1,2),$ and $(1,0).$
You can check that it encloses total area $1$--as a density function must.

If you want to find $P(0 < X \le 1/2)$ for this simple case,
you can see that it is equal to 1/4. The area of the small
triangle under $f_X(x)$ and above $(0, 1/2)$ is half its base
times its height: $(1/2)(1/2)(1) = 1/4.$

If you know some calculus, you can find that the CDF of this
random variable $X$ is $F_X(x) = x^2,$ for $0 < x \le 1.$
Then $$P(0 < X \le 1/2) = F_X(1/2) - F_X(0) = (1/2)^2 - 0 = 1/4.$$

*Notes:* (1) In this simple example, calculus isn't *necessary*
because you can find areas under $f_X$ using elementary geometry.
(2) Using $<$ on one side of inequalities and $\le$ on the other
is just a 'convention' (habit). The $\le$ could just as well be $<$
because there is zero probability at any individual point.
(3) In many cases (such as the simple example above) you never have to deal with $-\infty$ because
all of the probability is in some finite interval.
(4) In some examples, using calculus is *impossible* and other
methods need to be used to find areas under density curves. The
famous normal distribution ("bell-shaped curve") is an example of
this. Instead of finding $F$, you use tables of probabilities, a
calculator, or statistical software.